# Check if there is an error?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air, adobe

I have an ANE that is not supported by MAC, so I have to test it on the iPhone (iPhone-ARM).  I'm not sure when I get errors in the application, but I can tell there is one when the game starts to lag a lot.  Is there a way to see if there is an error in flash and convert the `Error` to a `String`?

I could use the debugger, but I have testers that don't have flash nor this application and would like them to recieve a message when there is an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use global error handling to catch uncaught errors. You can get error messages and stacktrace info from the error object.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/global-exception-handling.html

Comment: Uncaught errors are runtime errors, so you'll be able to catch them anytime during your application.